# Set the last column width to the margin using landscape and longtable environments

Tags: margins, longtable, columns, landscape

I have the following table:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[
top=2.5cm,
left=2.5cm,
bottom=2.5cm,
right=2.5cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\sloppy
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
{\footnotesize%
\begin{longtable}{llp{3cm}ccccl}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{\textbf{Head 1}}} &
\multirow{2}[4]{*}{\textbf{Head 2}}                     &
\multirow{2}[4]{3cm}{\textbf{Head 3}}                   &
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Head 4}}                     &
\multirow{2}[4]{*}{\textbf{Head 5}}                 \\
\cmidrule{4-7}                                  &   &   &
\textbf{Head 4.1} & \textbf{Head 4.2} & \textbf{Head 4.3} & \textbf{Head 4.4}&\\
\midrule
Column 1    &
Column 2 text   &
Column 3 has long texts &
Column 4 long center texts  &
Column 5 long center texts  &
Column 6 long center texts  &
Column 7 very long center texts &
Column 8 some text  \\
\end{longtable}%
}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

The 8th column is outside the page margins. How can I set the last column width to the space reaming after the previous column, considering the multirow that was used for the headings?

[image]

EDIT 1:
The table doesn't let enough space to the last column

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[
top=2.5cm,
left=2.5cm,
bottom=2.5cm,
right=2.5cm,
showframe
]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\sloppy
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
{\footnotesize%
\begin{longtable}{llp{3cm}ccccl}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Head 1}}} &
\multirow{2}[4]{*}{\textbf{Head 2}}                     &
\multirow{2}[4]{3cm}{\textbf{Head 3}}                   &
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Head 4}}                     &
\multirow{2}[4]{*}{\textbf{Head 5}}                 \\
\cmidrule{4-7}                                  &   &   &
\textbf{Head 4.1} & \textbf{Head 4.2} & \textbf{Head 4.3} & \textbf{Head 4.4}&\\
\midrule
Column 1    &
Column 2 text   &
Column 3 has long texts &
Column 4 long cent texts    &
Column 5 long cent texts    &
Column 6 long cent texts    &
Column 7 long cent texts    &
Column 8 some text  \\
\end{longtable}%
}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

There is a new table with a little bit more space

[image]

Comment: welcome to tex.se. your table already without last column occupancy width of landscape page.  is it acceptable if after first column all columns have equal width and cells in case  of longer cell content it can be broken into more lines?

Comment: @Zarko only the text on the Columns 3 and 8 can be broken

Comment: than you haven't any chance to fit table on the page wit readable text. with `\resizebox` you can squeeze it to page with, but it is not readable anymore.

Comment: @Zarko I'll edit the question, giving more space to the last column

Comment: @Zarko Could you help me with the edited question, please?

Comment: i'm not wizard and i'm not able store an elephant into kitchen fridge ... :). i see only reasonable solution provided by @AboAmmar answer. another possibilities is reduce font size to `\tiny` (not recommended).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need the capabilities of `tabularx` but at the same time the table should continue over the next pages; this can be achieved by the `ltablex` package.

**Edit:** Seeing your comment above, I have chosen the `X` column type for columns `3` and `8` only, but other columns are set as `l` and `c` since they cannot be broken. To take advantage of all the available height, I defined

```
\newlength\mywidth
\setlength\mywidth{\textheight}
```

to be used for `tabularx`'s width.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[
top=2.5cm,
left=2.5cm,
bottom=2.5cm,
right=2.5cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\sloppy
\begin{document}

\newlength\mywidth
\setlength\mywidth{\textheight}

\begin{landscape}
{\footnotesize%
\begin{tabularx}{\mywidth}{@{}llXccccX@{}}
\toprule 
&   &   & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Head 4}} & \\ \cmidrule{4-7}
\textbf{Head 1} &
\textbf{Head 2} &
\textbf{Head 3} &
\textbf{Head 4.1} & \textbf{Head 4.2} & \textbf{Head 4.3} & \textbf{Head 4.4}&\textbf{Head 5} \\
\midrule
Column 1    &
Column 2 text   &
Column 3 has long texts &
Column 4 long center texts  &
Column 5 long center texts  &
Column 6 long center texts  &
Column 7 very long center texts &
Column 8 some text  \\
\end{tabularx}%
}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: but OP don't like to have such solution (see my comments above) :-)

Comment: @AboAmmar this code works for a table spread in 2 or 3 pages?

Comment: @DanielValencia - Yes, as I stated in my answer, `ltablex` combines the advantages of both `tabularx` and `longtable`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, setting the  six last columns to `X` type:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\sloppy

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\small\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ll>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X*{6}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\toprule
& & & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Head 4}} \\
\cmidrule{4-7}
 \textbf{Head 1} & \textbf{Head 2} & \textbf{Head 3} &
\textbf{Head 4.1} & \textbf{Head 4.2} & \textbf{Head 4.3} & \textbf{Head 4.4}& \textbf{Head 5}\\
\midrule
Column 1 &
Column 2 text &
Column 3 has long texts &
Column 4 long centred texts &
Column 5 long centred texts &
Column 6 long centred texts &
Column 7 long centred texts &
Column 8 some text \\
\end{tabularx}%
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or this, with columns 3 and 8 twice as wide as the other X columns:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ll>{\hsize=1.5\hsize\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X*{4}{>{\hsize=0.75\hsize\centering\arraybackslash}X}>{\hsize=1.50\hsize\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
 \toprule
 & & & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Head 4}} \\
\cmidrule{4-7}
 \textbf{Head 1} & \textbf{Head 2} & \textbf{Head 3} &
 \textbf{Head 4.1} & \textbf{Head 4.2} & \textbf{Head 4.3} & \textbf{Head 4.4}& \textbf{Head 5}\\
 \midrule
 Column 1 &
 Column 2 text &
 Column 3 has some long texts &
 Column 4 long centred texts &
 Column 5 long centred texts &
 Column 6 long centred texts &
 Column 7 long centred texts &
 Column 8 has some very long texts \\
 \end{tabularx}%
```

[image]